# How to put a check mark on the selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to do so that when you click on an image, a check mark like ✓ appears in the upper right corner of the selected image? The idea is that when the other one is selected, the icon of the other disappears and follow the same effect that I have worked on.

I have searched but I can not find the correct solution with Jquery or css

```css
.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}

.cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}

.cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc +.fa-check{
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
            display: show;

}

.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
            filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
       -moz-filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
            filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cc-selector">

    <div>

        <input checked="checked" id="checkRabbit" type="radio" name="rabbit" value="rabbit">

        <label class="drinkcard-cc rabbit" for="checkRabbit">

            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000012999353/237fc396ff1510bb381c2a534a834fd7.jpeg" class="img-responsive">

        </label>

    </div>

    <div>

        <input id="checkMonkey" type="radio" name="monkey" value="monkey">

        <label class="drinkcard-cc monkey" for="checkMonkey">

            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/653420524975079424/VOzhTPsz_400x400.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">

        </label>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a click handler to the image. When the img is clicked add a class to the element to differentiate it as an active state.

You can have a svg or an img element ( which is the check mark ) set to `display: none` and toggle it when the element has an active state.

The example has the same functionality but instead uses a border to differentiate the active state.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});

function clickHandler(e) {
  let target = e.target;

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')].filter(item => item !== target).forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('active');
  });

  target.classList.add('active');

}
```

```css
.cc-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.cc-selector input:active+.drinkcard-cc {
  opacity: .9;
}

.cc-selector input:checked+.drinkcard-cc+.fa-check {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  display: show;
}

.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
  filter: brightness(1.04) grayscale(.5) opacity(1.2);
}

.item.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cc-selector">

    <div>

        <input checked="checked" id="checkRabbit" type="radio" name="rabbit" value="rabbit">

        <label class="drinkcard-cc rabbit" for="checkRabbit">

            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000012999353/237fc396ff1510bb381c2a534a834fd7.jpeg" class="img-responsive item active">

        </label>

    </div>

    <div>

        <input id="checkMonkey" type="radio" name="monkey" value="monkey">

        <label class="drinkcard-cc monkey" for="checkMonkey">

            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/653420524975079424/VOzhTPsz_400x400.jpg" class="img-thumbnail item">

        </label>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Good way. Now .. what change must be made to keep selected by default with the red border that you have put? Because I have in html check = "checked" but when I run the snippet I have to click to show the edge

Comment: It is currently driven by the `active` class on `img` element. Just add `active` to the first image

Comment: One last question: What change must be made so that the edge is not removed when clicking on the same element? That is to say: I leave the edge active as I told you before, but if I click again on the same element the edge goes away

Comment: @JohnJ. You are welcome. Just get rid of the if condition and always add the `active` class on click. Check the updated snippet

Comment: Excellent. He almost reached the goal but he answered quickly. Thank you very much for helping me. Good Thursday